# Send Form Name to JS/jQuery & Serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization

It works when inputs are empty but as soon as they have a value it returns nothing.

UPDATE: It's if I send the form without entering any inputs, then enter the inputs and send again, that nothing is returned.

NEW UPDATE: I hadn't included the function I created to handle errors. That function appears to be causing the problem somehow. I'm adding the code below. When the function is removed from the code, the error does not occur.

Error Function

```
function showError(id){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
        $("#"+id).css( "background-color", "#ffcece" );
        $("#sendBtn").attr("onclick","sendForm()");
        $('#sendBtn').css("background-color", "#29559c");
        document.getElementById('sendBtn').innerHTML = "Submit Application";
        $('#frm-err').css("color", "red");
        $('#frm-err').html('Please fill out the entire application');
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="membershipForm" id="membershipForm" onsubmit="return false">
    <input required type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name">
    <input required type="text" id="Pin" name="Pin" placeholder="Pin">
    <button id="sendBtn" onclick="sendForm(form.name);return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS/jQuery

```
function sendForm(formName) {       
    var formData = $("#"+formName).serialize().replace(/\+/g,'%20');
    alert(formData);
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Alerted `Name=Test&Pin=1234`

Comment: @abney317 Try submitting the form without entering the inputs, then enter the inputs and send. Does it return nothing?

Comment: Works fine still

Comment: @abney317 When I submit without data, then submit again with data, the error occurs in both FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using

Comment: @abney317 <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Correction: I was linking to the full script during that test. Not the script I have here. When I use the scaled down script I posted here the error does not occur.

Comment: I have a function that handles error and that seems to be responsible for the problem. I'll update the question and add that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function handling the errors I reset the onclick but failed to include the (form.name).